# Building a small responsive web design for desktop view, tablet view, and mobile

Tags: html, css

I am new to coding and trying to figure out how to use HTML, CSS and media queries together, to create a 3 item menu of equal containers side by side in desktop view.

In tablet view the menu items shift to 2 menu items staying on the first row and the 3rd menu item shifting to the second row but spans the length of the 2 menu items on the first row.

In mobile view all 3 menu items are stacked one on top of the other. See images below. My breakpoints for desktop are 992px or greater, tablet view is 768px and 991px, and mobile is 990px or less.

I have written the following HTML and CSS in an attempt to duplicate what the images are showing. My menu items do not respond to the media queries I put in my css file. I can only use basic responsive framework for the project.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

div.container1 {
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.container2 {
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.container3 {
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div#menu1 {
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  height: 20px;
  width: 125px;
  background-color: #FF66B2;
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div#menu2 {
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  height: 20px;
  width: 125px;
  background-color: #990000;
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div#menu3 {
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  height: 20px;
  width: 125px;
  background-color: #FFE5CC;
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/* For tablets and large phones: */

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  background-color: green;
  .col-m-1 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-m-2 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-m-3 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}


/* For Desktop */

@media only screen and (min-width:992px) {
  .col-1 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-3 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Our Menu</h1>

<div class="container1 .col-1 .col-m-1">
  <div id="menu1">Chicken</div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor
  </p>
</div>

<div class="container2 .col-2 .col-m-2">
  <div id="menu2">Beef</div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="container3 .col-3 .col-m-3">
  <div id="menu3">Sushi</div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor.
  </p>
</div>
```

Desktop:
[image: Desktop]

Tablet:
[image: Tablet]

Mobile:
[image: Mobile]

Comment: It's simple if you know about flex box css : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @GeekyQuentin, thank you for your help. I noticed in tablet view, the Sushi item did not span the length of the chicken and beef items when it shifted to the second row. Can you help with this? Also the breakpoints used in the media queries were not applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reworked your code a bit and did this using flexbox and nth-child selectors. Exactly what you asked for in the 3 sample screenshots, done with a mobile first approach.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
    
h1 {
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-container .item {
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  margin: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.flex-container .item .menu {
  height: 20px;
  width: 125px;
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  
  transform: translate(1rem, -1rem)
}
.flex-container .item:nth-child(3n+1) .menu {
  background-color: #FF66B2;
}
.flex-container .item:nth-child(3n+2) .menu {
  background-color: #990000;
  color: white;
}
.flex-container .item:nth-child(3n+3) .menu {
  background-color: #FFE5CC;
}

.flex-container .item > *:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.flex-container .item > *:nth-last-child(1) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .flex-container .item {
    width: calc(50% - 2rem);
  }
  .flex-container .item:nth-child(3n+3) {
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  }
}
@media (min-width:992px) {
  .flex-container .item,
  .flex-container .item:nth-child(3n+3){
    width: calc((100% / 3) - 2rem);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Our Menu</h1>

<div class="container flex-container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="menu">Chicken</div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="menu">Beef</div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="menu">Sushi</div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="menu">Chicken</div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="menu">Beef</div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="menu">Sushi</div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for help. I have rules I need to follow. See rules below. I think I can not use some of the method you used even though they worked. It needs to be more simple responsive design.

Comment: Desktop version breakpoint 992px and above
Tablet version breakpoint 768x and 991px
Mobile version breakpoint =< 767
Page layout <h1>, add 3 sections <div> all in a row w/ text.
Use media queries to build breakpoints of sections
Desktop view 992px and above, 3 sections should be all equal on the screenUse percentage to define width, use float. 
•Section title region should always be in top right corner of section, use relative, absolute positioning to offset

Comment: @BrianShelby All of these rules have been met other than I'm using flex instead of float. Media queries work with a mobile first approach meaning that the code is targeted at mobile, then 768px is the next breakpoint, and 992px is the last breakpoint -- this is typically considered the best way to do responsive design. So it's just the flex vs float thing

Comment: I understand, thank you, I am doing a course that seems a bit out dated so I was just trying to do what was asked in the assignment. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You checked correctly?

When I checked I got each item aligned down perfectly, and don't use

```
<div class="container1 .col-1 .col-m-1">
```

like this - use a div container

```
<div class=containers>
```

Then in css use flex or block or whatever you want, that would be easier to use.

And in css

```
/* For tablets and large phones: */
```

under this there is a mistake, you don't set the element for `background-color:green`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all of your containers in a new `<div>` container with class `container-box` and add the following CSS styles to it.

```
.container-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

---

Applying these modifications to your code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.container1 {
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.container2 {
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.container3 {
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div#menu1 {
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  height: 20px;
  width: 125px;
  background-color: #FF66B2;
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div#menu2 {
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  height: 20px;
  width: 125px;
  background-color: #990000;
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div#menu3 {
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  height: 20px;
  width: 125px;
  background-color: #FFE5CC;
  float: right;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/* For tablets and large phones: */

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  background-color: green;
  .col-m-1 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-m-2 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-m-3 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}


/* For Desktop */

@media only screen and (min-width:992px) {
  .col-1 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-3 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Our Menu</h1>

<div class="container-box">
  <div class="container1 .col-1 .col-m-1">
    <div id="menu1">Chicken</div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="container2 .col-2 .col-m-2">
    <div id="menu2">Beef</div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="container3 .col-3 .col-m-3">
    <div id="menu3">Sushi</div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```